# Why does my variable get forced initialized to 0 even when it shouldn't?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to count and update the immediate neighbors of a cell with non zero values. So left, right, upper, lower, upper-left ... 
Anyway all the eight directions and the cell itself.

```
int grid[100][100];

int genNeibrs(int x, int y, int n, int m)
{
    m--;
    n--;
    int c = 0, xs = ((x - 1) < 0) ? 0 : (x - 1),
        xe = ((x + 1) > n) ? n : (x + 1),
        ys = ((y - 1) < 0) ? 0 : (y - 1),
        ye = ((y + 1) > m) ? m : (y + 1);

    for (auto i = xs; i <= xe; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = ys; j <= ye; j++)
        {
            if (grid[i][j])
                ++c;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

void getGrs(int n, int m)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < m; j++)
            if (grid[i][j])
            {
                int q = genNeibrs(i, j, m, n);
                if (q)
                    grid[i][j] = q;
            }
    }
}
```

Here the value of q becomes 0 for successive iterations other than 0,0 for
`grid =  {{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 <repeats 91 times>}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 <repeats 91 times>}, {0 <repeats 100 times>} <repeats 98 times>}`, m and n being 9 and 2 respectively.
While debugging with gdb the function `genNeibrs` returns as expected but over execution I managed to pin it down to the line where q is being initialized. It somehow gets initialized to zero even when it shouldn't.
So what am I doing wrong?
Expected value of `grid = {{1, 0 ,3 ,3 ,0, 3, 4, 5, 3, 0 <repeats 91 times>},{0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0 <repeats 91 times>}, {0 <repeats 100 times>} <repeats 98 times>}`
Anyway the grid's values doesn't change.

Comment: My advice is not to initialize all your variables on the same line. Other programmers will not like reading that..

Comment: That ternary needs to be tackled to the ground and wrangled into submission. That's completely out of control and totally unreadable. As drescherjm says, initialize *one variable per line*. This makes it very clear what you're doing as readability is extremely important for code.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do and how can it be used correctly? These are just functions. No example is given of usage. One thing you'll want to remember is **avoid global variables** and instead pass through things like `grid` as an argument to any functions that need it.

Comment: *is this a compiler problem?* -- The compiler you're using is being used by thousands of programmers, hundreds (if not thousands) of companies, and is maintained by some of the best programmers in the world.  So all bets are that it isn't a compiler problem.

Comment: FYI:  Common industry coding guidelines recommend declaring or defining one variable per line.  It has negligible effect on the build but makes reading the code a lot easier.

Comment: FWI, you may have more efficient code by checking all 8 conditions rather than using a loop.  Usually, having a slightly longer function that is working correctly is better than have a compressed function that has defects.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I get what you are trying to say.
The first function works as expected (in GDB). But `int q = genNeibrs(i, j, m, n);`
q gets 0 even when it shouldn't have.

Comment: Is the biggest call `getGrs(100, 100)`, or `getGrs(99, 99)`?  Because xe and ye are being capped at that value, inclusively (as used in the loop).

Comment: I think you have an off by 1 error with xe and ye with your usage of <=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, when you debug, you should step into the problematic function to see what is going wrong in there. However, since I spotted suspicious code when looking for typical typos for those using your cryptic coding style: compare the following lines.

```
int genNeibrs(int x, int y, int n, int m)
int q = genNeibrs(i, j, m, n);
```

Tell me, what should happen if instead of "m and n being 9 and 2 respectively", you had "m and n being 2 and 9 respectively"?

**Lesson:** *Use meaningful variable names!* The letters "m" and "n" are visually similar. It is much easier to spot "rows" and "columns" being reversed than "m" and "n".

Comment: Yup turns out it was the cause of all.

Comment: … and then `n` and `m` are ordered distinctly unconventionally. I stumble each time I read that function-declaration.